# Images are overwriting

Tags: ios, multithreading, uiimageview, uicollectionview

I am building a project where I am using threads for the first time.

I have taken a collectionView where I want to show the images. I am taken 10 image URLs in an array. Now, after downloading the images will show in the collection view.

But when I am running my project the images are coming but the images are continuously overwriting.

I am confused about how to show the all the images in the collection view.

My code is

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

     self.arrImages = @[@"http://helpyourselfimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Nature-Pictures-HD1.jpg",
                   @"http://helpyourselfimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Beautiful-Island-Wallpaper.jpg",
                   @"http://hdwallpapers4u.eu/wallpaper_3840x2160/booty_hose_sofa_thongs_girl_beautiful_nature_ultra_3840x2160_hd-wallpaper-242177.jpg",
                        @"http://www.pageresource.com/wallpapers/wallpaper/chelsea-logo-nature-hd-beauty.jpg",
                   @"http://dowehwall.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/hd-wallpaper-beautiful-nature-hd-wallpaper-nature-beautiful-hd-426201-download-this-wallpaper-use-for-facebook-cover-edit-this-wallpapers.jpg",
                   @"http://imgstocks.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/Beautiful-nature-cool-images-background-hd-wallpaper-beautiful-nature.jpg",
                   @"http://ghost2-gbj.rhcloud.com/content/images/2013/Dec/beautiful_nature_wallpapers_for_desktop_high_definition_wallpaper.jpg",
                   @"http://www.hdwallpapersos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/nike-air-max-nature-beautiful-pictures.jpg",
                   @"http://www.3dwallhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/white_tiger_beautiful-wide.jpg",
                   @"http://mobiledady.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Beautiful-HD-Nature-Wallpapers-For-Desktop-2013-2014-9.jpg"];

    [self fetchData];



}

-(void)fetchData{

    dispatch_queue_t imageQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Image Queue",NULL);
    for (NSString *urlString in self.arrImages) {
    dispatch_async(imageQueue, ^{

            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            if (!self.imageNature) return;

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [self.imageNature setImage:image];



            });

        });
    }



}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{
    return 1;
}


-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [self.arrImages count];

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"collectionCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.imageNature = (UIImageView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1];

    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)btnAlrt:(id)sender {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"BOOM!!" message:@"Main Thread Is Running" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [alert show];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}


 @end
```

Comment: Is self.imageNature a UIImageView? If yes, you're setting all the images to the same UIImageView

Comment: What you have there is (besides not working properly) not a good pattern for asynchronous download.. Take a look at asynchronous NSURLConnection or libraries like AFNetworking or SDWebImage

Comment: Dude! I have understood what are you saying, but just tell me how can I show all the images in the collection view one after another?

Answer (score 0):

They are many ways to do this, but let me explain first that you have to download a image in synchronous way because you dont have anything to manage, so just download first image and add into your array, do this for all and you will be able to make it work.

Another way which I have used is with Afneworking which give a method to cache your image but still you have to manage little things.

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;
```

Comment: Since I am new in iOs developing I haven't come to know about AFNetworking. The task that is assigned to me is threading. I have to download the image in background thread and after downloading the images will show in the collectionView. Can you just tell me, according to my code, after downloading, can I save the images in an array? If yes then how? @Retro